# Deploying Silex on webserver, can't mount controllers

Tags: php, controller, silex

I have a problem deploying my Silex application to a webserver, on my localhost everything works fine.

With some echo's I could find the line of code that creates the error and it's in my app.php file.

```
<?php
use ScoutsEnGidsenNieuwland\Helper;

// Bootstrap
require __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bootstrap.php';

$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) use ($app) {
    $helper = new Helper();

    $loginform = $helper->loginForm($app);

    if ($code == 404) {
        return $app['twig']->render('errors/404.twig', array(
            'user' => $app['session']->get('user'),
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            'pageTitle' => 'Error',
            'activatedMenuItem' => 'home',
            'loginform' => $loginform->createView()
        ));
    } else {
        return 'Shenanigans! Something went horribly wrong // ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
});
echo('works until this part!');
// Mount our Controllers
$app->mount('/', new ScoutsEnGidsenNieuwland\Provider\Controller\HomeController());
```

I get no error, just a blank page with the echo, so obviously something is wrong with mounting the controllers.

I also tried an echo at the start of the HomeController() but this one didn't came through.
I'm guessing the file was not found.

Anybody who had a similar problem like mine?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What's in your error log?

Comment: Do you call `$app->run()` somewhere?

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file (or other) configured - http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html?